# How to buffer gRPC messages using Envoy or Nginx proxy?

Tags: nginx, grpc, envoyproxy

I'm implementing hot update for my service behind a proxy. During the update process my service goes into a quiescent state for some time so I want to buffer the gRPC messages received during this time so that I can process them later (after update). Does envoy or Nginx proxy provide such a feature?